# C# - Display Files in a Folder on Button Click

Tags: c#

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio and i have a WPF project where i would like to be able to click a button and it displays all the .txt files in a specified folder.

Is it possible to display the text files that are in the folder in a list?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sure it is possible. Where is your problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? Can you show the code where you got stuck?

Comment: I'm going to leave a this here before this thread closes up. @MagicRecon the reason you are receiving the down votes is probably because there is already a lot of information on this subject, not only on StackOverflow but also across the web. StackOverflow does not cater well to tutorial like questions as much as we would like to help you if the thread closes up that is going to be difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
string directory = @"C:\";

List<string> textFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.txt").ToList();

// You can now you textFiles as a DataSource for your List Control
```

you can add `using System.IO` directive and remove it from the above code;

Comment: Considering the nature of the question it might be wise to include the actual using System.IO as well. Also consider showing that this is a string array and not just use the var type. Change that and you keep my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `Directory.GetFiles` method

Answer (score 1):

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.txt");

this should work i guess :)

or visit this : http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/